# DOS: How to add text in the MIDDLE of a file, instead of rewriting it?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

Using the DOS `int 21h` API, how can I write text in the middle of the file instead of REwriting it?  i.e. do an "insert" operation, not an overwrite.

Comment: by seeking to the desired position ... What is your current code ?

Comment: You should read up on [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here.

Comment: I am using int 21, 40. But I have a problem: I want to add my line in the middle of the file and NOT replace it with the text that is already in the file.

Comment: This isn't an asm question, it's a DOS system call API question.  I assume the answer is the same as for Unix: `open(filename, O_APPEND|O_WRONLY)`, or `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` to seek to the end of an already-open file (which you opened without truncation).  Oh, in the middle?  You need to read into memory the part of the file after the insertion point, and then write it back out after.

Comment: Understood, thank you for your answer, @ray - i will try better next time, just needed to get the answer quickly.

Comment: @Zivile: But we try to make sure questions and answers here remain useful long after both of us are gone :)

Comment: @ray: I edited the question for him.  I wouldn't be surprised if it's a duplicate, but I still upvoted it back to zero, since it's not a bad question now (even though the OP couldn't find the edit button, only comment).

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for this. I will have the fact in my mind that i have to formulate questions for others to be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't an asm question, it's a DOS system call API question.  The answer is the same whether you're writing in C or directly in asm.

You need to seek to the insertion point, and read everything from there to EOF into memory.  Then write your new data, then write the previous contents after that.  If that's more memory than you can allocate, you'll need to write a new file.  (copy the beginning, write your new text, then copy the end.)

---

You're probably thinking, "why can't you just tell the OS what you want so it can just modify the metadata, instead of forcing you to rewrite the data?".  Well, because I assume DOS doesn't provide an API for that.  Also, because it could only work with block-size granularity.  If the text in the rest of the file should now line up differently in filesystem data blocks, it has to get rewritten.

DOS was written for FAT filesystems, and fancy file-allocation-manipulation functions are more of a recent innovation, it seems.  Obviously making heavy use of this operation would result in fragmented files (not allocated contiguously on disk).  Perhaps the rise of SSDs has made operations that can't be done without fragmentation more interesting to support, because Linux has been gaining support for more and more operations like this with [`fallocate(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html).

Linux supports inserting blocks into the middle of existing files without rewriting them:  [`fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_INSERT_RANGE, offset, len)`, available since Linux 4.1](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) should do the trick.

The inverse operation, collapsing a range without leaving a hole, has been available since Linux 3.15.  The command-line [`fallocate(1)` utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html) supports this with `fallocate -c`.

All of these ops only work with filesystem-block-size granularity (typically 4kiB).  If you're adding or removing exactly that much text, but not lined up on a 4k boundary, you could use `fallocate` and only have to rewrite the neighbouring pages, instead of the whole rest of the file.

---

If you want to be able to do this efficiently, use a data structure in your file similar to what text editors do to allow efficient insertion at any point: A [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)).  A [gap buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer) is not a good choice, because it only maintains one efficient insertion point at a time.

Probably put "index" at the end of the file, after all the chunks of text, so it can be rewritten easily.  This would mean you couldn't just feed the file to other programs, because it would be in your custom format.  You'd need a tool to produce a flat version every time you needed that, so a Rope on disk is only useful if you need to modify more often than you need to read (with programs that can't use a custom library).

Comment: Wow, that is some deep informative answer. Thank you for such answer, it helped me a lot to understand. I will definitely use this information when writing my program.